# Limit of a sequence: proof $\lim(a_n/b_n) \to L/K$

Tags: calculus

$$ \lim_{n\to  \infty}  (a_n) = L$$
$$ \lim_{n\to  \infty}  (b_n) = K$$

I need to proof that: 
$$ \lim_{x\to  \infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n} = \frac{L}{K}$$

I have to get to something like that: $$ \left| \frac{an}{bn} - \frac{L}{K} \right| < E $$
I tried:

$$ \left| \frac{a_n}{b_n} - \frac{L}{K} \right| = \left| \frac{a_nK-b_nL}{b_n K} \right| =  \frac{|a_nK-LK+LK-Lb_n|}{|b_n||k|} = \frac{|K(a_n-L)-L(b_n-K)|}{|b_n||k|}$$
in this stage I don't know what to do.
I can't use Triangle inequality because there is a minus ! my teacher wrote something like this:

$$ \frac{|a_nK-LK+LK-Lb_n|}{|b_n||k|} \le \frac{|a_n-L||k|+|L||b_n-K|}{|b_n||k|}$$
and I don't understand how he get to the right side. **my question is, how he get to the right side?** because when I tried, I got this minus that interrupt and I cant use triangle inequality

Comment: Might you have meant $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}$ rather than $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}$? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: You can bound $b_n$ and use each limit definition, you just have to find the right $\epsilon$

Comment: $a_n -L$ is less then $\varepsilon$ for $n>n_1$ and you can use similar argument for $b_n-k$.. For the denominator you know that $b_n$ is bounded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\frac{|a_nK-Lk+LK-Lb_n|}{|b_n||K|}$ = $\frac{|(a_n-L)K+L(K-b_n)|}{|b_n||K|}\leq$ $\frac{|a_n-L||K|+|L||b_n-K|}{|b_n||K|}$.

$|a_n-L|<\epsilon_1$, $|b_n-K|<\epsilon_2$ and since $b_n$ is convergent, hence it is bounded. So you can bound the above expression.

Comment: how did you replace L(K-Bn) to |L||Bn-K| ? It suppose to be |L||K-Bn|

Comment: if you are inside modulus value then $|K-b_n|=|b_n-K|$.

Comment: modulus value = absolute value? this rule is for any x and y? |x-y| = |-x+y| ? I tried and it seems to be a rule.. |5-2| = 3 , |-5+2| = |-3| = 3

Comment: Actually. $|x-y|=|(y-x)*-1|=|-1||y-x|=|y-x|$

Answer (score 1):

If you already know that for $an\rightarrow a \quad$ and  $bn\rightarrow b \quad$ that $\quad an*bn\rightarrow (a*b)$
You can do the following (Proof that $\; \frac{1}{b_n}\rightarrow\frac{1}{b}$):
$$|\frac{1}{b_n}-\frac{1}{b}|=|\frac{b_n-b}{b_n*b}|...$$